# How to Do Quick Sort In Ada

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ada, quicksort

How do I do a Quick Sort in Ada?
I would also love a function to test it. 
I am using GPS as the IDE

Comment: Pretty much the same way you'd do it in any other language (though the array syntax is a bit more convenient).

Comment: the thing is i dont know Ada really, i am dabbling in it. So if someone knows how to do it, i would love to see it, and compare to other languages

Comment: rosettacode.org is a nice site to compare languages. is this for homework?

Comment: nah, we learn java in school. i am looking into different languages, my attempt to get more rounded..lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) in Ada may be found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Ada). Note you'll need all three files.

Comment: Thanks. I tried dropping it in the IDE. i got the following errors, do you know why?

Invalid byte sequence in conversion input

"Element_Array" is undefined

"Element_Type" is undefined

"Index_Type" is undefined

Comment: Not sure, I've never done anything with Ada - I just decided to lookup an example and that's what I found: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Ada

Comment: -1: incomplete copy-paste from other source. providing the link should have been enough. you missed the ads file.

Comment: 1) this is not the place to discuss the errors, 2) without the errors, nobody can help you, 3) go back to rosettacode and read the whole Ada part. it consists of three files. GPS relies on the project settings, try without first (on commandline).

Answer (score 3):

If Quicksort is not strictly necessary, why not use the generic [Containers.Generic_Array_Sort](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-A-18-16.html) procedure ?

EDIT: Most implementations of Generic array sort will use Quicksort, so check what your uses, and you might not have to implement your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the code for QuickSort at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Ada

Comment: If you are just mucking with the language and want to see how quicksort would be done in it (perhaps compared to other languages), Rosettacode is the place to go.

Answer (score 0):

## Code

Compiled on Windows 10 with GNAT GPL 2015.
Converted from [rosettacode quicksort pseudocode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort).

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;

procedure Main is

   generic
      type Element is private;
   procedure Generic_Swap (A, B : in out Element);
   procedure Generic_Swap (A, B : in out Element) is
      Temp : constant Element := A;
   begin
      A := B;
      B := Temp;
   end;

   generic
      type Index is (<>);
      type Element is private;
      type Vector is array (Index range <>) of Element;
      with function "<" (Left, Right : Element) return Boolean is <>;
      with function ">" (Left, Right : Element) return Boolean is <>;
   procedure Generic_Quicksort (Item : in out Vector);
   procedure Generic_Quicksort (Item : in out Vector) is
      procedure Swap is new Generic_Swap (Element);
      pragma Suppress (Overflow_Check);
      pragma Suppress (Range_Check);
      Pivot : Element;
      Left : Index;
      Right : Index;
   begin
      if Item'Length > 1 then
         Pivot := Item (Item'Last); -- Choose the pivot element.
         Left := Item'First;
         Right := Item'Last;
         while Left <= Right loop
            while Item (Left) < Pivot loop
               Left := Index'Succ (Left);
            end loop;
            while Item (Right) > Pivot loop
               Right := Index'Pred (Right);
            end loop;
            if Left <= Right then
               Swap (Item (Left), Item (Right));
               Left := Index'Succ (Left);
               Right := Index'Pred (Right);
            end if;
         end loop;
         Generic_Quicksort (Item (Item'First .. Right));
         Generic_Quicksort (Item (Left .. Item'Last));
      end if;
   end;

   type Planet is (Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto);
   type Planet_Season_Array is array (Planet range <>) of Float;
   procedure Sort is new Generic_Quicksort (Planet, Float, Planet_Season_Array);
   procedure Put (Item : Planet_Season_Array) is
      use Ada.Text_IO;
      use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
      use Ada.Strings.Fixed;
   begin
      for I in Item'Range loop
         Put (Tail (I'Img, Planet'Width));
         Put (Item (I), 2, 2, 0);
         New_Line;
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end;

   Item : Planet_Season_Array (Planet) := (0.8, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7);

begin
   Put (Item);
   Sort (Item);
   Put (Item);
end;
```

## Output

```
MERCURY 0.80
  VENUS 0.10
  EARTH 0.40
   MARS 0.90
JUPITER 0.00
 SATURN 0.70
 URANUS 0.50
NEPTUNE 0.30
  PLUTO 0.70

MERCURY 0.00
  VENUS 0.10
  EARTH 0.30
   MARS 0.40
JUPITER 0.50
 SATURN 0.70
 URANUS 0.70
NEPTUNE 0.80
  PLUTO 0.90
```